# Change HTML form value with JavaScript before it's submitted

Tags: javascript, html

With an external JavaScript file, I'm changing the value of this button below to '5'.

This works, I used console.log to check if the value indeed got changed to '5'.

```
<form action="getdata.php" method="POST">
  <button type="submit" class="firstHeavyGame button" name='storage' value=''>PRESS THE BUTTON</button>
</form>
```

Then, when this button is clicked it sends the value to the php site where it processes the data. 
BUT, I think then clicking this button, the value gets reset to '' '' (blank). Basic HTML (I'm a newb).
So the php script is not receiving any data.

I checked to see if everything else is working by manually entering the value:

```
<form action="getdata.php" method="POST">
  <button type="submit" class="firstHeavyGame button" name='storage' value='5'>PRESS THE BUTTON</button>
</form>
```

This works correctly (gets the number 5 and passes it on to the php file where it gets processed).

Now I know I'm making a newbie mistake but I can't seem to find an answer for my example when doing my research.

Hope you guys can help me out!

Comment: Welcome @number42! Can you please give us some additional info, or the code you're using for changing the value of the button?

Comment: Hi @BrettDeWoody HK KNVB's answer is working. Thank you for the effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
<form action="getdata.php" method="POST" onSubmit="setValue(this)">
   <button type="submit" class="firstHeavyGame button" name='storage' value=''>PRESS THE BUTTON</button>
</form> 
<script>
    function setValue(v) {
         v.storage.value="5";
         return true;
     }
</script>
```